# mounting a windows software raid volume in linux

Tags: linux, raid, windows-server-2000

i have a windows 2000 server box with 6 drives in it configured as RAID 5 using windows dynamic volumes. windows will not boot.

is it possible to mount this volume using linux? i looked at dmraid but it doesn't appear to support windows software raid.

acceptable answers also include live or resuce boot CD's (such as TRK) that would allow me to access the volumne without having to boot windows from the boot drive in the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can do this from linux. Looks like your best option would be to use a [BartPE Windows Live CD](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) to access the RAID volume and rescue the data.

Comment: Doing some quick Googling, it doesn't look like BartPE supports dynamic disks. Some commercial data recovery products do.

Comment: you would have thought it would occur to me that i can make a PE disk from a server 2003 CD, but it didn't. duh!

Comment: ok, i have confirmed that this works if you user a windows 2003 server cd. windows 2000 server is not supported.